# tinymce 4 editor.insterContent does not go on new line after insert

Tags: javascript, wordpress, editor, tinymce-4

I made a wordpress plugin which adds a custom button in tinymce. Bu the problem is when the plugin inserts the text the cursor does not go in new line but stays inside the div. How can I tell tinymce to go in new line and leave the inserted div.

my code:

```
onclick: function() {
            editor.windowManager.open( {
                title: 'Insert special text',
                body: [{
                    type: 'textbox',
                    name: 'text',
                    label: 'text'
                }],
                onsubmit: function( e ) {
                    var text = e.data.text;
                    editor.insertContent('<div class="special">' + text + '</div> \n');
                }
            });
        }
```

This works correctly it inserts the div that i want with the class special and the text in it, but how can i go to new line make the cursor leave that div after the insertion is made?

I want this because when the publisher adds the special div and then hits ENTER it creates another empty div with class special. I want just one div and then leave that div, go to new line and proceed with writing.

Comment: Nice question..